# How is Leading Zero working in php?

Tags: php, leading-zero

Let's suppose I have a code which outputs `$i` as

```
$i = 016;
echo $i / 2;
//ans will be 7
```

I know that the leading zero indicates an octal number in PHP, but how is it interpreted, how can it be executed? Can somebody share its execution step by step? What is the role of parser here? I have researched a lot and read all the previous answers but none are having any deep explanation.

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: The interpreter does the conversion during the compilation phase. The first line of code produces the same opcodes as `$i = 14;`.

Comment: What do you mean "deep explanation"? The parser sees an integer with a leading 0 and interprets it as octal number, thats's it!? :D

Comment: Yes you can answer it in answer column by giving a proper explanation, will appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you preceed integers with zero in PHP, in that instance, `029`.

It becomes octal.

So when you echo that, it will convert to its decimal form.

Which results to:

```
echo 016; //14 (decimal) valid octal

echo 029; // 2 (decimal) -  Invalid octal
```

Actually, its here stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Valid octal:

```
octal       : 0[0-7]+
```

**Note:** Prior to PHP 7, if an invalid digit was given in an octal integer (i.e. 8 or 9), the rest of the number was ignored. Since PHP 7, a parse error is emitted.

Comment: Yes your answer seems perfect to explanation only thing I will love to edit is 029 to 2 as it is not giving perfect decimal number instead use 016 to 14, so that anyone can interpret it easily. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @JayminNoob: 029 is an invalid octal literal, so what is it supposed to do then?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have mentioned same thing, above what if it is invalid octal literal what it does next?

Comment: @JayminNoob i have addec 016 and also for invalid octal i added a note at the end of answer

Answer (score 2):

The **octal** numeral system, or oct for short, is the base-8 number system, and uses the digits 0 to 7.

Octal numerals can be made from binary numerals by grouping consecutive **binary digits** into groups of **three** (starting from the right).

For example, the binary representation for decimal 74 is 1001010. Two zeroes can be added at the left: (00)1 001 010, corresponding the octal digits 1 1 2, yielding the octal representation 112.

In your question `$i = 016;` is calculated by the interpreter and produces `$i = 14;`(which is the equilevant decimal number)

Then you simply divide it by 2, which outputs 7.

Comment: what if it is invalid octal literal what it does next?